# Couchbase on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, couchbase

I just downloaded Couchbase Server on my MacBookPro running Mavericks 10.9.2 with 4GB of RAM. I did the initial configuration thing and deleted all the buckets including the default. Then I proceeded to create a new bucket. But I noticed that the server status immediately went to pending (yellow). Later, when I tried to access the bucket from my node.js code, it kept throwing a protocol error.
Is there something I am doing wrong? Can someone point me to a good example/tutorial about creating a bucket in Couchbase.
Thanks
José

Comment: it says protocol error

Comment: even from the Couchbase server admin console it seems that creating a bucket does not work. I just don't know why.

Comment: If this happened to me and I didn't have any data to preserve I would just start with a fresh install. If I did have data I'd make a backup of it and do that anyway. If the fresh install keeps having the problem, we can try to drill into your environment to figure out why. Look here for the data files: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Couchbase/var/lib/couchdb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (pending server, and unable use sync_gateway to connect to it).

I was able to resolve the problem by

1. quitting Couchbase Server
2. deleting the Couchbase folder from `/Users/<yourname>/Application Support`
3. starting up Couchbase Server again
4. using all of the defaults for setup